# Using orderBy in ng-options in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I do have objects of the following form:

```
item = {key1: {count: x}} where x is an integer
```

I would like to sort my options in my template using count.
I am using ng-options in the following way:

```
data-ng-options="key1 for (key1, sub_item) in item | orderBy: 'sub_item.count'"
```

Unfortunately, the sort isn't working. Any idea how I could achieve this ?

Comment: _orderBy_ working only with array, but your _item_ is `object`

Comment: You should trying to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474920/order-by-object-key-in-ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) you have to set the `orderBy` value in quotes:

```
orderBy: 'sub_item.count'
```

Comment: I did try to change it, but it is still not ordering unfortunately. Thanks though.

Comment: It doesn't work because orderBy needs an array.  You have an object.  Convert it to an array and you'll be all set.