# Angular Country sortBy

Tags: angularjs, select, countries

I have created a Angular Select box for countries. My array looks like this:

AD: "Andorra"

AE: "United Arab Emirates"

AF: "Afghanistan"

AG: "Antigua and Barbuda"

AI: "Anguilla"

And my NgRepeater looks like this

```
<li nya-bs-option="(k, v) in fields.country.available" data-value="v" data-label="{{v}}">
```

As you can see, The 'Key' is automatically getting alphabetically arrange in order. However I wish for the 'Value' to be arranged in alphabetical order. I have tried:

```
<li nya-bs-option="(k, v) in fields.country.available | orderBy:'v'" data-value="v" data-label="{{v}}">
```

But this didn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you to remove the quotes from the `v`?

`orderBy:v` instead of `orderBy:'v'`

Comment: javascript objects have no order, switch to using array

Comment: Yeah I have tried that and it didnt work :(

Comment: How do I do that @charlietfl ?

Comment: Have you tried my updated solution below? If you have additional questions just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your array seems more like an object as far as I can see from `<key>:<value>` structure. In this case you would need to write an own filter for `orderBy` because angular cannot sort object keys with this filter.

See also: [Order by Object key in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474920/order-by-object-key-in-ng-repeat)

Despite of the solution in the thread above, I would suggest to use another structure for the countries if possible:

```
[{id: 'AD', name: 'Andorra'}, ...]
```

Then you can do this in `ng-repeat`:

```
country in fields.country.available | orderBy: 'id'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to do this, as the data is being produced from Moltin API.

Comment: see my updated answer. This might work for you, since it is done without transforming the original object.

Comment: Gave it a whirl but getting 'Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!'

Comment: Sorry, I would have seen this if I tried it by myself. It cannot work becasuse $digest() is fired on each iteration by applying the filter. I removed my update to avoid confusion. The quickest way is still to manipulate the original datastructure. is there no possibility to save the API response in the scope to a new structure?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. And by doing this way, the countries are automatically put into alphabetical order :)

HTML:

```
<ol class="nya-bs-select" ng-model="data.ship.country" name="ship_{{fields.country.slug}}">
    <li nya-bs-option="v in sortable" data-value="v[0]">
        <a>{{v[1]}}</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Controller:

```
var countries = fields.country.available,
    sortable = [];

for (var country in countries){
  sortable.push([country, countries[country]]);
}       
sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1]
});

$scope.sortable = sortable;
```

Comment: whoops make a slight error. should be resolved now :)