# why orderBy not working in ngrepeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use  `orderBy`  in `ng-repeat` using angular js.but it fail to sort my list .here is my code ?

how to sort my code

https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/1921/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lines = {
        "a" : {name:"bb"},
        "aa": {name: 'aa'},
        "zz": {name:"zz"},
        "oo": {name: 'oo'}, 
        "kk": {name:"k"},
        "j" : {name: "a"},
        "n" : {name:"n"},
        "c" : {name: "c"}
   }
}
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474920/order-by-object-key-in-ng-repeat

Comment: Duplicate Question

Answer (score 0):

You will have to turn your object into array in order to get it to work

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="line in lines | orderBy:'name'">
    <div class="preview">{{line.name}} {{$index}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lines = [
       {name:"bb"},
    {name: 'aa'},
    {name:"zz"},
    {name: 'oo'}, 
    {name:"k"},
    {name: "a"},
    {name:"n"},
    {name: "c"}
];
}
```