# AngularJS oderBy ob key value map

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way of order a key- value map like this:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.carryForwardInformation" data-ng-show="value.value != null && value.value != '00:00'">
            <td><b>{{key | translate}}</b>:</td>
            <td>{{value.value}}</td>
            <td>{{value.startDate}}</td>
            <td>{{value.endDate}}</td>
            <td>{{value.date}}</td>
        </tr>
```

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.carryForwardInformation | orderBy:key"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order by Object key in ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474920/order-by-object-key-in-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `orderBy` filter over an object. It only works over an array. So basically you have two options:

**1. Order your object by key inside the controller and iterate over that sorted object ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/gju2YIZJYSXR1dxxqbJe?p=preview))**

*CONTROLLLER*

```
var objectUnsorted = {
    "key2":{"id":2,"name":"Lisa","date":"11/11/2016"},
    "key3":{"id":3,"name":"Alice","date":"06/03/2017"},
    "key1": {"id":1,"name":"Christina","date":"17/05/2016"}
};

vm.sortedObject = orderByKey(objectUnsorted);

function orderByKey(data){
    let ordered = {};
    Object.keys(data).sort().forEach(function(key) {
      ordered[key] = data[key];
    });

    return ordered;
}
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.soretdObject">
```

**2. Convert your object to an array and user `orderBy` filter ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/KzkNwRPb346pt43WP5nJ?p=preview))**

*CONTROLLER*

```
var objectUnsorted = {
    "key2": {"id":2,"name":"Lisa","date":"11/11/2016"},
    "key3": {"id":3,"name":"Alice","date":"06/03/2017"},
    "key1": {"id":1,"name":"Christina","date":"17/05/2016"}
};

vm.dataArray = Object.keys(objectUnsorted).map(function (key) { 
    var obj = objectUnsorted[key];
    obj.key = key;

    return obj; 
});
```

*HTML*

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in vm.dataArray | orderBy:'key'">
```

---

** A third option could be do it with a **filter** ([CHECK THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474920/order-by-object-key-in-ng-repeat/26478321#26478321)). But I don't believe that is a good approach convert to array in every digest cycle with a filter.

Answer (score 0):

orderBy looks for the properties you tell it to, within the current element from your array.

You should use the following syntax

```
orderBy: 'key'
```

Check this plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: I have updated the answer with a plunker link, please refer for a detailed understanding on how to use it

Comment: It's empty plunkier