# angular filter orderBy:key not working in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to displaying countries name in one select box and states name other select box , country name not coming acceding order, what can i do, please help me, i tried code bello code.

html:

```
---
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div>
  <select id="country" style="width:250px;" class="" name="countryName" ng-model="state1" ng-change="displayState(state1)" ng-required="true">
                           <option ng-repeat="(key,country) in countries | orderBy:key"  value="{{key}}">{{country[0]}}</option>
                    </select>

</div>{{countries}}{{state1}}

<div><select id="state" ng-model="cities">
 <option ng-repeat="(state,city) in states[state1]" value="{{city}}">{{city}}</option></select></div>
</div>
```

script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.states =  {
     "IN":[
       "Delhi",
       "Goa",
       "Gujarat",
       "Himachal Pradesh",
     ],
     "AU":[  
      "Australian Capital Territory",
      "New South Wales",
      "Northern Territory"
      ]
   };
   $scope.countries =  {
      "IN": ["India"],
       "ZA": ["South Africa"],
       "AU": ["Austria"],
       "BG": ["Bulgaria"],
            "RW": ["Rwanda"]
     }
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

Comment: This may help..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26478321/2754029

Comment: As far I know orderBy works for Array, but you have json object.. you should consider using toArray filter and then try sorting.. or you should write a simple filter function in your controller who does this sorting.

Comment: not working, working i tried, I updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc3n55d2/27/, please check once

Comment: I have updated fiddle, please check and let me know if that is not what you are looking for

https://jsfiddle.net/h2fftLqo/3/

Answer (score 2):

The code:

```
<option ng-repeat="(key,country) in countries | orderBy:key"  value="{{key}}">{{country[0]}}</option>
```

will not work, because the built-in orderBy filter will no longer work when iterating an object. It’s ignored due to the way that object fields are stored.

So you can transferm your object into an array something like this:

```
$scope.countriesArray= [];
angular.forEach($scope.countries, function(value, key) {
    $scope.countriesArray.push({
        NewKey: key,
        NewValue: value
    });
});
```

And then use:

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countriesArray | orderBy:'NewKey'">  
</li>
```

The plunkr that can help (not created by me):

http://plnkr.co/edit/fSjledOzPqm6LzGtmCt9?p=preview

Let me know if you face any issue

Comment: not working please check on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc3n55d2/27/

Comment: I believe you have problem with countries only, where it is not able to sort properly. I have updated the fiddle... where I made this work. Countries are being sorted properly now. 

I have removed some of the elements, if you have problem with those element let me know the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/h2fftLqo/3/

Comment: your getting in dropdown only key, but i want values , IN means Inida

Comment: Ohd.. just replace the NewKey with NewValue.. Is this what you wanted?

https://jsfiddle.net/h2fftLqo/4/

Comment: India has states that states not loading second dropdown, my jsfidle coming  everything but filter only not working "https://jsfiddle.net/Lc3n55d2/28/"

Comment: you had problem with countries dropdown, so i removed states and fixed countries.. I think if you try to understand the code, you will be able to add that yourself.. anyway i am now going back to my work.. in sometime i will be back here and will try to see of I can fix your problem

Comment: OK.. I tried to do what you wanted.. Please check this

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc3n55d2/30/

and let me know if you want anything else here. @sitabane

Comment: @sitabane , have courtesy and accept the answer please, if it solves your problem